# C++ fork process but not as child

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I have a command which provides diagnostic information about a running process. I would like to trigger/execute this command just before the process crashes and capture the output to stdout/file.

However, this command is not able to run as a child of the process it monitors. The command is detecting this. It needs to fork as a separate parent process.

Is there a way to spawn a new process, executing the command but not as a child?

Comment: Open a file and use replace the child process's `stdout` file with the new file using `dup2`?  Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: @StephenNewell Must admit i've never done anything like this before. At the moment i've just used pipe() and popen() to execute the command, when I discovered I cannot run it from within the same process.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very basic example using the method I asked about in a comment:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int result = fork();
    if(result == 0) {
        int fd = open("test", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        assert(fd >= 0);
        int result = dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        assert(result != -1);
        char * const argv[] = {"ls", NULL};
        char * const env[] = { NULL };
        result = execve("/bin/ls", argv, env);
        assert(result != -1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You'll have to tweak it for your needs, but this will store the results of `ls` in the file "test".  The trick is that `dup2` replaces the standard out file descriptor `STDOUT_FILENO` with a copy of the file descriptor to our newly opened file, so `ls`'s output is redirected.

I think you'll be able to use this to get the output from your command.

Comment: Hi, not sure if you saw my edit to the question? When I trief forking myself the diagnostic detected that it's a child of the parent and it's still refusing to run. I assume a parent cannot fork a parent, so I may need to make the parent process the diagnostic, fork the child (my application) and when my application signals, the parent can then run the diagnostic command?

Comment: I did not see your edit.  Does the diagnostic tool take a path/arguments for the process to monitor?

Comment: Yes there is one argument, but the command is structured: "command something" where something is an argument. However, there are no switch/flag dashes. The argument is defined by a space after the command.

Comment: So why not do something like `monitor-tool your-command your-command-args`?  That'd be similar to how `valgrind` and other dynamic analysis tools work.